# what are the limits of what a Flutter app can't do vs a native iOS/Android app

Tags: flutter

I'm new to Flutter having been burned attempting to use PWA/Chrome to create a mobile app with native behaviour. So I don't get fooled again. I'm trying to understand what, if any, are the restrictions of Flutter on mobile.

Specifically, my app needs the following features (I'll use the Android terms but the equivalent iOS features also apply):-

- receive Firebase Cloud Messages
- those messages to be silent (ie. they are consumed by the app rather than go straght to a notification)
- background http access (an Android Service)
- local storage (more SQL-Lite than KV pairs)
- Raise device notifications ...
- ... such notifications to have a deep link into the app, and ...
- ... have the ability to send a reply from the notification without opening the app
- intercept incoming SMS (Android Telephony.Sms.Intents )
- desktop widget
- read the user's Gallery
- access Location
- intelligently guide the user to enable any necessary app permissions, such as Location, read Gallery, notifications, lock screen, etc

Is this kind of native behaviour within Flutter's realm?

Comment: Since you (or someone) can write platform channels, the answer is simply: Flutter can do everything a native app is permitted to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flutter, over the past years has grown mature enough to be doing all the above functionalities.
Here is the list of packages that you can use to make the app.

1. receive Firebase Cloud Messages ==> [firebase_messaging 12.0.2](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging)
2. those messages to be silent ==> [notifications 2.0.1](https://pub.dev/packages/notifications)
3. background http access ==> [background_fetch](https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch)
4. local storage ==> [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)
5. Raise device notifications ==> [in_app_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_notification)
6. deep link into the app ==> Can use [branch.io](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_branch_sdk)
7. have the ability to send a reply from the notification ==> using platform channels
8. intercept incoming SMS ==> [Telephony](https://pub.dev/packages/telephony)
9. desktop widget ==> currently not possible using flutter, MacOS yes, in some ways.
10. read the user's Gallery ==> [Photo_Gallery](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_gallery)
11. access Location ==> [Location](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator)(Fine Access)
12. intelligently guide ==> [Coach_Mark](https://pub.dev/packages/tutorial_coach_mark)